# Boot from USB, but run on auxiliary hard drive

Tags: boot, usb, drive, optical

I have a Dell Vostro 1700 that a friend gave me because it died.

On investigation I found that it no longer recognized the internal hard drives, but booted fine from an Ubuntu CD or from Ubuntu on a USB flash drive. It currently runs from the USB, but painfully slowly. I have a caddie that replaces the optical drive with a hard drive, but it is not recognized as a bootable drive so I can install Ubuntu on the hard drive and the laptop runs great until I shut down.  So what I would like to do is get it to boot from the USB flash drive, but then run from the hard drive in the CD caddie. Is this possible and how would you do it?

I am doing this as a project to learn and just because.

Answer (score 2):

I could solve the same issue with the following method.

I'll consider that for the rest of the article (change it as per your own configuration):

- the hard drive is `sda` and the boot partition is `sda1` (which maps to `(hd1,gpt1)` in GRUB, `(hd0)` being the GRUB USB)
- `/dev/sda1` contains a `/boot/vmlinuz` kernel and `/boot/initrd.img` disk
- the Ubuntu bootable USB is `sdb` under Ubuntu Live
- the to-be GRUB USB is `sdc` under Ubuntu Live

Boot on the Ubuntu Live USB:

1. Insert the new USB and create on it an ext4 partition *with grub_bios flag* (that will be `/dev/sdc1`) and a *second* ext4 partition with "boot" flag (that will be `/dev/sdc2` on which GRUB will boot)
2. Mount the second partition so `grub-install` can create the `/boot/grub` files: `mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt`
3. Install GRUB on it: `grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt /dev/sdc`
4. Edit file `/mnt/grub/grub.cfg` with the following content:

```
set root=(hd1,gpt1)
linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
initrd /boot/initrd.img
boot
```

Reboot on the GRUB USB and it should be booting your hard drive.

EDIT: As per @kenn's comment: it's better to use partitions UUIDs or labels instead of direct links to hard drive. The UUIDS (and labels) are available in your Ubuntu Live under `/dev/disk/by-partuuid` or `/dev/disk/by-partlabel`. Then use in your `grub.cfg`:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz root=PARTUUID=<partition UUID>
```

or:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz root=PARTLABEL=<partition label>
```

Comment: The order of the drives are erratic, it may change in every boot. Try adding `UUID` of the drive such as `root=UUID=uuidofthepartition`

Comment: @kenn Thanks, I'll add that. In the meantime I found my problem (no `boot` at the end of the `grub.cfg` file, sigh).

Answer (score 1):

In general it is possible to boot from USB and run from a hard disk.  Install to the caddy disk, install again to another USB, and edit the USB's grub boot commands in /boot/grub/grub.cfg to point to the caddy disk.  The trick will be to figure out what letter the caddy will get when there is only one USB present. See http://www.linlap.com/dell_vostro_1700 for some specific video and wireless issues.
  Your situation may have special problems:

1. Why is the internal hard disk not seen?  This could be an incipient motherboard failure.  USB booting may still work (for awhile longer), but no hard disk, even in the caddy may be referenced.
2. The caddy may cause grub problems.  Any reference to a caddy on an old HP caused grub to hang for a minute.  No reference within grub to the caddy worked, although the caddy worked fine as extra storage when running from another root.

Comment: I have no idea why the internal HD are not "seen", but the USB and caddie drive have worked consistently.  The card reader works, but not to boot from.   I will eat those grubs when I come to then.  Thank you so very much for the clear concise answer.